# Python: How to list only sub-directory files in Jupyter Notebook using rglob?

Tags: python-3.x, file-handling

I am writing a script on Jupyter Notebook (Python 3) to execute ipynb files in sub-directories. I am also constrained to be in the Current Directory.
**I want to output list of files of *.ipynb extension within sub-directory and not the files in the current directory.**

From the Current Directory, I am executing this code:

```
CurrentPath=pathlib.Path.cwd()
ipynbList=list(CurrentPath.rglob('*.ipynb'))
```

[Current file in current directory is not intended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lSOO.png)

But, as output, I am getting the current file (which has this code) as well. Since executing the current file will become a recursive nightmare, I am looking for a clean solution to list files ONLY in sub-directories.

I thought this would be straight forward, but did not find any solution.

Would appreciate if someone can point me to a solution. Thanks in advance!